# AWS SES ConfigurationSetName and template parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm having trouble sending emails with the ConfigurationSetName and template parameter.

If sent by the sendTemplatedEmail function WITHOUT the 'ConfigurationSetName' parameter, I receive the email.

With the same function (sendTemplatedEmail) but with the parameter 'ConfigurationSetName', I do not get the email!

If sending by the sendEmail function, with or without the parameter 'ConfigurationSetName' I receive the email in both tests of this function.

All submissions return success and the MessageId of the tests with the sendTemplatedEmail function are these:
Without the ConfigurationSetName: 0100016055cdcd01-1f16a6cc-4e6b-48b8-9812-faa66be34e3b-000000
With ConfigurationSetName: 0100016055cc9265-be9e3b26-15f3-47af-bfae-477780d3fabc-000000